# App crashes when I try to get value of textfield by tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am dynamically adding textfields to my app though when I try to access them by the tag like this:

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
```

Then try and get the value:

```
NSString *val = textField.text;
```

The app crashes and I get this error:

```
-[UIView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1edb0c30
```

Any help on how to fix this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: Never use `0` as a specific tag since that is the default for all views.

Comment: Set your textField with maximum tag as possible. Ex : textField.tag = 32222;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default `tag` value is 0. So here `[self.view viewWithTag:0];` you can receive a view that is not UITextField and not responds to `text`.

You can check object's class using

```
[your_object isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go even further than some have said, rather than using tags you can refer to your specific textfields by reference:

```
// Create an array to hold your textfields
NSMutableArray *textFields = [NSMutableArray array]

// Create your textfields and add them to the array
UITextField *textField;
for (NSUInteger idx = 0: idx++; idx < numberOfTextFieldsYouWant) {
    textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:<whateverYouWant>];
    [textFields addObject:textField];
}
```

Since you are adding the objects to an array, rather than using the tag value 0, 1, 2... you can just access it by it's index in the array

So **instead of**

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
```

You can write:

```
UITextField *textField = [textFields objectAtIndex:0];
```

It's a lot cleaner, doesn't rely on magic tags, and you have an array of all your dynamic textfields that you can remove, or change in one place.